# What is wrong in this code snippet, writing server side variable on the page as property of asp.net server controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

ASPX Page

```
<asp:Label ID="lbk" runat="server" Text='<%= _imgPath %>' />
```

Code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _imgPath = "MyName";

    }
```

My expectation was that it should render

```
<span id="lbk">MyName</span>
```

But it is rendering

```
<span id="lbk"><%= _imgPath %></span>
```

Is this correct behavior?

Comment: <%= _imgPath %> is not a construct supported by the Label server control. Label controls support the <%# %> data binding construct, but not <%= %>

Comment: Thanks everybody for suggestion. I am aware about setting the Label text from code behind but that is not my requirement. That is why I explained the scenario. @Adrian, I tried that way too but it didn't work. Any one there?

Comment: You need to use a different approach. What are you trying to accomplish? You can simply render MyName in your ASPX as <span id="lbk"><%= _imgPath %></span> for example. Why are you required to use the approach that you've described?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbk" runat="server" Text='<%# _imgPath %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbk.Text = "MyName";

}
```

you dont need `_imgPath`.

Answer (score 0):

For something simple like setting the text of a Label, use the `Page_Load` event in the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lbk.Text = "MyName";
    }
}
```

Of if you'd rather use a script on the page, you can do this:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            lbk.Text = "MyName";
        }
    }
</script>
```